# Spring JDBC Template SQL-Query filtered by date

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc

I need to get filter my query by two dates. This is working when I query for it with the Oracle SQL Developer or right out of Eclipse:

```
select * from TABLE where rechnungs_eingang >= '06.08.2012' AND rechnungs_eingang <= '06.08.2015')
```

But if I try to get the data via my webservice I've implemented with Spring 4 I get this exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: StatementCallback; SQL [select * from TABLE where rechnungs_eingang >= '06.08.2012' AND rechnungs_eingang <= '05.05.2014')]; ORA-01843: not a valid month
; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

What and why is happening here?

Comment: is that SELECT statement the actual one you used in sql developer? i don't see how that would have worked as there is no date format used. Is rechnungs_eingang a DATE column?

Comment: Yes - rechnungs_eingang is a DATE-colum. It works just like that in the SQL Developer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [`to_date`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm) function and provide a [date format mask](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924) if you pass in a string value in the query. Like this: `to_date('06.08.2012', 'DD.MM.YYYY')`.

The reason why you got this working in SQLDeveloper without providing a date format is likely that the default format used in your locale is `'DD.MM.YYYY'` and the implicit `VARCHAR`->`DATE` conversion happens correctly.